# Angular2 ngFor different Id to function

Tags: angular

I have a NgFor from a service, and I want to create a label with a click event. If a click the label change color. This is my code but if a click all the labels changes.

```
 <ion-slide *ngFor="let plan of plans | slice:0:4; let i=index">
  <ion-grid class="box-plan">
    <ion-label [attr.id]="i" class="text-box-add" 
      (click)="addToCartPlans(plan)" >{{text}}</ion-label>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-slide>


  addToCartPlans(plan: any) {
let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
this.lines[currentIndex].noPlan = true;
this.hasPlans = this.lines[currentIndex].noPlan;
this.lines[currentIndex].plans = plan;
this.selected = true;
this.text = 'Selected';
```

}

Comment: have you made model for plans?

Comment: `this.text` and `{{text}}` all refer to a single variable

Comment: I'm tring this, but doesn't work: